Python, pandas parse number and string from string
In Python, I want to parse a string and return the numeric portion (may or may not have decimal point) as a float and return the suffix as a string. Examples are:

7.1inch -> 7.1, inch

7.1” -> 7.1, “

7in -> 7.0, in

-10dB -> -10.0, dB

-10.2dB -> -10.2, dB


There’s no space between the numeric portion and suffix. Also, I want to apply this to a Pandas DataFrame column that has this format so that I can sort by the floating point value. I then want to append the suffix back to each element in the column after the sort.
How to do this?

Use a regular expression to extract the numeric part and appendix as strings, convert the numeric part to float, sort and then either use original column or convert numeric part back to string and concatenate with the appendix.

...But if you go that route, be aware that a nontrivial regex may be required, especially if you want to allow scientific notations like -1.23e+45.  See also regular expression for finding decimal/float numbers?

You don't need to create new columns for that, you can just use sort_values with a custom key function that uses regex and returns the digits in a numeric type.
The regex pattern works for the numbers provided in the question. If you have numbers in different formats in your data, the pattern may need to be adjusted.
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {"measurements": ["7.1inch", "7.1”", "7in", "-10dB", "-10.2dB", "text"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def extract_numeric(s):
    match = re.match(r"(-?\d*\.?\d+)", s)
    if match:
        return float(match.group(1))

df = df.sort_values(by="measurements", key=lambda x: x.map(extract_numeric))

  measurements
4      -10.2dB
3        -10dB
2          7in
0      7.1inch
1         7.1”
5         text


Implementation of @michael-butscher proposal on your given example.
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['7.1inch', '7.1“', '7in', '-10db', '-10.2db']
})

_regex = r'(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)([^\d]+)'

def split_str(s):
    match = re.match(_regex, s)
    if match:
        number = float(match.group(1))
        suffix = match.group(2)
        return [number, suffix]
    
df['num'], df['str'] = zip(*df['col1'].apply(split_str))
df.sort_values(by='num', inplace=True)

result
       col1     num    str
 4    -10.2db  -10.2   db
 3     -10db   -10.0   db
 2      7in     7.0    in
 0      7.1inch 7.1    inch
 1      7.1“    7.1    “


Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {"col1": ["7.1inch", "7.1”", "7in", "-10dB", "-10.2dB", '1.0in', '10in', '20dB']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
    col1
0   7.1inch
1   7.1”
2   7in
3   -10dB
4   -10.2dB
5   1.0in
6   10in
7   20dB


Code
I'm not sure exactly what desired output you want.
If you want to separate the float and string parts into columns, use the following code:
out1 = df['col1'].str.extract(r"(?P<num>-?\d*\.?\d+)(?P<str>.+)")

out1:
     num   str
0    7.1  inch
1    7.1     ”
2      7    in
3    -10    dB
4  -10.2    dB
5    1.0    in
6     10    in
7     20    dB


If you just want to sort by the size of the float, use the following code:
out2 = df.sort_values(
    'col1', 
    key=lambda x: x.str.extract(r"(-?\d*\.?\d+)")[0].astype('float')
)

out2:
    col1
4   -10.2dB
3   -10dB
5   1.0in
2   7in
0   7.1inch
1   7.1”
6   10in
7   20dB

